# How to import into a dll and exported array?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have a debug dll library which I try and export and array like so:

debuglib.h

```
#define MAX_DEBUG_EVENT_COUNT_PER_FRAME 65533
__declspec(dllexport) DebugEvent currentFrameDebugEventArray[MAX_DEBUG_EVENT_COUNT_PER_FRAME];
```

The library builds fine but then when I try to import that array into another dll that needs to use that array:

```
__declspec(dllimport) DebugEvent currentFrameDebugEventArray[MAX_DEBUG_EVENT_COUNT_PER_FRAME];
```

I get this error/warning message:

```
" warning C4273: 'currentFrameDebugEventArray': inconsistent dll linkage"
```

Am I using the dllexport/dllimport declarations incorrectly?

Comment: You probably `#include "debuglib.h"` into the file where `__declspec(dllimport) ...` line appears. So now the compiler sees two definitions of the same variable, one with `__declspec(export)` and another with `__declspec(dllimport)`

Comment: yes to both of you. The first comment is what made me realize why I needed that #if #else macro for a dll export. Thanks!